# pass value from stringbuilder to textview

Tags: android, stringbuilder

I am trying to get words from several `EditTexts` and display them using `TextView` without using any layout. But the program is force closed every-time I run it.

> LOGCAT: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.tablelayout/com.example.tablelayout.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        int count = 10;
        linearLayout.addView(tableLayout(count));
        linearLayout.addView(submitButton());
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }

    private Button submitButton() {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setHeight(WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setText("Submit");
        button.setOnClickListener(submitListener);
        return button;
    }

    TextView txt=new TextView(this);



    // Access the value of the EditText

    private View.OnClickListener submitListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (EditText editText : editTextList) {
                stringBuilder.append(editText.getText().toString());


            }

            txt.setText(stringBuilder.toString().trim());
        }
    };

    // Using a TableLayout as it provides you with a neat ordering structure

    private TableLayout tableLayout(int count) {
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        int noOfRows = count / 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
            int rowId = 5 * i;
            tableLayout.addView(createOneFullRow(rowId));
        }
        int individualCells = count % 5;
        tableLayout.addView(createLeftOverCells(individualCells, count));
        return tableLayout;
    }

    private TableRow createLeftOverCells(int individualCells, int count) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
        int rowId = count - individualCells;
        for (int i = 1; i <= individualCells; i++) {
            tableRow.addView(editText(String.valueOf(rowId + i)));
        }
        return tableRow;
    }

    private TableRow createOneFullRow(int rowId) {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        tableRow.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            tableRow.addView(editText(String.valueOf(rowId + i)));
        }
        return tableRow;
    }

    private EditText editText(String hint) {
        EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setId(Integer.valueOf(hint));
        editText.setHint(hint);
        editTextList.add(editText);
        return editText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full logcat error please

Answer (score 1):

```
  TextView txt=new TextView(this);
```

you can't declare and initialize a **class member** View at the same time, because the `Context` is [not yet valid](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle)

change it to:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<EditText>();
    private TextView txt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        txt = new TextView(this);
        // other code
```

also I noticed that you are not adding this `View` to any of the containers that your provided to `setContentView`. The suggestion will fix the crash but you will not see the `TextView`'s content

Answer (score -1):

Exception shows problem is in your manifest file.
Your package name is manifest tag and your activity are in different locations.

Comment: Blackbelt, I do am able to stop the force close with your suggestion. What do I need to do to display the TextView's contents dynamically? The Button click still shows nothing.